# Change width of parent div according to content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have number of of child `div`s in a parent `div`. It may be minimum 2 to maximum 8. I have kept the width of child `div`s 25% fixed. The problem is when there are 2 or 3 child `div`s, then first 50% or 75% of parent `div` is used to display these `div`s. But I want to use center 50% or 75% of parent `div` to display these `div`s. In case there are more than 4 child `div`s then I want to display first row of parent row without any change and want to use centered 25% for 5th `div`, centered 50% for 5th and 6th and centered 75% for 5th, 6th and 7th div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Block1</p>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="block1">
            <img src="hoels.png" />
            <p>Banquet Halls</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block1">
            <img src="hoels.png" />
            <p>Resorts</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block1">
            <img src="hoels.png" />
            <p>Hotels</p>
        </div>
        ---------------------------
        ---------------------------
        ---------------------------
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:991px;
}
.banner{
    padding:20px;
}
.block1{
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    text-align:center;
}
.block1 img{
    width:100%;
max-width:100px;
}
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/7fpt4m5e/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #01 (Using Flexbox):**

You can use css3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Add following css on parent element:

```
.banner {
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}
```

***Note***: You will need to remove `float` from child elements as with `flexbox` it is unnecessary.

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:991px;
}
.banner{
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  padding:20px;
}
.block1{
  background: green;
  width:25%;
  text-align:center;
}
.block1 img{
  width:100%;
  max-width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Block1</p>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Banquet Halls</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Resorts</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Hotels</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Farm Houses</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Farm Houses</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Farm Houses</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Approach #02(Without Flexbox):**

You can use `display: inline-block` on child elements. As we can affect `inline` and `inline-block` elements with `text-align` center property so we will use this trick to center align child elements.

Add following css:

```
/* Following css should be added on parent */
.banner {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  font-size: 0;
}
/* Following css should be added on child elements */
.block1{
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  width:25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:991px;
}
.banner{
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  font-size: 0;
  padding:20px;
}
.block1{
  letter-spacing: 0;
  background: green;
  font-size: 14px;
  width:25%;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.block1 img{
  width:100%;
  max-width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Block1</p>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Banquet Halls</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Resorts</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Hotels</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Farm Houses</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Farm Houses</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="hoels.png" />
      <p>Farm Houses</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> `font-size` and `letter-spacing` properties are being used in parent
>   and child elements to remove excess space caused by `inline-block`. For more ways of removing this space, check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: Thanks Sir..Working both for me...Which one is better according to you ?

Comment: @Ashish I would recommend using `flexbox`. All latest browser are supporting this. But if you need support in old browsers you should use 2nd method as it will work perfectly even in IE8.

Comment: Is it possible to change width of block1 div to 50% or 33% in case of 2 or 3 child div when resizing window to mobile view...

Comment: @Ashish yes you can use media queries to override `width` to 50% or 33% as you would like.

Comment: Yeah i know that but i want to change the width in case to 2 or 3 child div only...

Comment: @Ashish do you wants this? [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xtnurwf8/)

Comment: @Ashish Without `flexbox` its difficult. The only way is to use css `table` properties. One row cannot have more than 4 items. For more items you will need to add another row.

Comment: @Ashish You can check this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xtnurwf8/2/). I've created a demo for you. But as I said earlier, items won't wrap in 2 lines in this case. If you will add 5th item in a row, it will adjust in the same row accordingly. However this method will work in almost all browsers as well.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your efforts...but it will be difficult for user to read content if there will be 6,7or 8 items in a row on a small screen...